# Getting/setting SQL Server instance settings

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to get the settings of a SQL Server instance via C# or TSQL? And then apply these settings to another SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get Sql Server Instance is

```
  Declare @key Varchar(100), @PortNumber varchar(20)

if charindex('\',CONVERT(char(20), SERVERPROPERTY('servername')),0) <>0

begin

set @key = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Microsoft SQL Server\'+@@servicename+'\MSSQLServer\Supersocketnetlib\TCP'

end

else

begin

set @key = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\Supersocketnetlib\TCP'

end

EXEC master..xp_regread @rootkey='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @key=@key,@value_name='Tcpport',@value=@PortNumber OUTPUT

SELECT CONVERT(char(20), SERVERPROPERTY('servername')) ServerName,

CONVERT(char(20), SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')) instancename
```

> OR

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')
```